# Set status of GitHub Actions workflow to skipped?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm working on improving a workflow that starts by checking if something needs to be done and then does it if it needs doing. Normally something needs doing once a fortnight.

Problem is that in the list of workflow runs, they all look the same. When it has to do something, the execution time is generally a bit longer, so you can find the jobs that actually did something by looking at the execution time, but it would be nicer if that was more clearly indicated.

**I was wondering if I could do the check and set the status to 'skipped', if nothing needs to be done?**

Comment: Are you running this on a `cron:` schedule? Why does it run when it's not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few options, you may like one more than another, let's see.

## 1. Use a cron schedule

I'm not sure why your job runs more often than needed, but if the job really only needs to run once every 2 weeks, you could set a cron schedule:

```
on:
  schedule:
    # * is a special character in YAML so you have to quote this string
    - cron:  '30 1 1,15 * *' # runs on the 1st and the 15th of the month
```

There may be a few other [cron schedules that might work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week).

## 2. Split your workflow into 2 jobs:

You could have a 1st job that calculates the condition and then a 2nd job that only runs if the condition is true:

```
jobs:
  check:
    outputs:
      environment: ${{ steps.check.outputs.should-run }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run a one-line script
        id: check
        run: |
          echo "should-run=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT         

  real-job:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     if: ${{ needs.check.outputs.should-run}}
     needs: check
```

## 3. Use workflow_run and split the workflow into 2.

Or you could split the workflow into 2 parts. The 1st workflow checks for the condition and only if true, triggers the 2nd workflow:

```
jobs:
  check:
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
            # Some condition to check whether to run the other workflow
            if ( ... ) {
              & gh workflow run the-other-workflow.yml --ref $env:GITHUB_REF --repo $env: GITHUB_REPOSITORY
            }
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The second workflow must have a `workflow_dispatch` trigger:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
```

Or [using GitHub Script](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v20#actions):

```
github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
  owner,
  repo,
  workflow_id,
  ref,
});
```

> You can use this endpoint to manually trigger a GitHub Actions workflow run. You can replace `workflow_id` with the workflow file name. For example, you could use `main.yaml`.
>
> You must configure your GitHub Actions workflow to run when the `workflow_dispatch` webhook event occurs. The `inputs` are configured in the workflow file. For more information about how to configure the `workflow_dispatch` event in the workflow file, see "Events that trigger workflows."
>
> The workflow permissions must have the `actions: write` permission to use this endpoint.

## 4. Cancel the current workflow using the API

Or you could use the API to [cancel the current workflow based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73788926/736079):

```
      - name: cancel run if none of files we look for changes has changed
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.any_changed != 'true'
        uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2

      # needed since the run is not cancelled immediately
      - name: wait for run cancellation
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.any_changed != 'true'
        shell: bash
        run: while true; do echo "Waiting for job to be cancelled"; sleep 5; done
```

And again, [using GitHub Script](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v20#actions):

```
github.rest.actions.cancelWorkflowRun({
  owner,
  repo,
  run_id,
});
```

> Cancels a workflow run using its id.
>
> You must authenticate using an access token with the repo scope to use this endpoint. GitHub Apps must have the `actions: write` permission to use this endpoint.

Comment: Thank you! 1. It's already a cron job, but we can't just run it every two weeks, as the exact day may change. 2. I already split the workflow into two jobs, which looks nice internally, but doesn't make a difference in the list of runs. 3. I tried something similar, but I used `uses`, which runs the worklow in place, rather than trigger another run that is displayed in another list. Any chance this is available in `github-script`, rather than using the `gh` command? 4. This looks like a hacky version of what I want. I suppose that means that the feature is missing.

Comment: Added github script example to #3.

Comment: Added github script example to #4.

Comment: All of the parameters for the github script examples are available as default github variables in the workflow.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the third option with GitHub scripts. Looks much better.